# Python3: using ttk after transition from 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I had been using Python2.7 on Windows 10 (64-bit). I recently decided to upgrade to 3.0 to update some legacy scripts.

I uninstalled Python27, and installed Python30 (I know I could supposedly run them concurrently on the same system, but I chose not to use that as a crutch) and updated the Windows %PATH%

My old scripts used ttk (import ttk).
I updated to use "from tkinter import ttk", but now I'm getting "cannot import name ttk". I'm assuming it's still somehow trying to link to the 2.7 Tkinter that no longer exists (and didn't contain ttk as a submodule since it was 2.7).

How can I get ttk to link correctly under Python3 after having used 2.7?

Comment: Is your file named "tkinter.py"?

Comment: *`from tkinter import ttk`*: Change to `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`